# Planning sequence of motion using arm_navigation/moveit

Tags: moveit, arm-navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I would like to planning sequence of motion with planning_component_visualizer. In the menu handler, there are only the option: set start and set end position.I would like to add option: "set next motion" which will swap the current end_state_ to a new start_state_ and selectmarker from the new start_state_ to set new goal. But I don't know how to set new start_state_ to "**current**" end_state_ (which is KinematicState), therefore, the start_state_ also changes when I start move the marker to the new end_state.

Is there any way to get the **current** KinematicState?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/47610/planning-sequence-of-motion-using-arm_navigation/moveit/) by [Tien Thanh](https://answers.ros.org/users/135/tien-thanh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 231 on 2012-11-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Problem is solved:

vector< double > state_vector;

gc.end_state_->getKinematicStateValues(state_vector);

gc.start_state_->setKinematicState(state_vector);

---

Originally posted by [Tien Thanh](https://answers.ros.org/users/135/tien-thanh/) with karma: 231 on 2012-11-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1